# HiveQl/sql logic to produce the below output

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am new to sql/hql.

I am having the below hive table

Card_ID  Mid      Address
------   -----   ---------------
1000     201     MG Road,bangalore
1000     301     MG Road,bangalore
1000     401     null

1000     501     null

2000     205     Plot # 5, Indira Nagar, Delhi

2000     305     Plot # 5, Indira Nagar, Delhi
2000     405     null

3000     109     psk road

3000     109     psk road

4000     202    null

4000     202    null

I need to prepare a hql to Identify Card_id's having mid address as null and not null

As output should be:

Card_ID  Mid      Address
------   -----   ---------------
1000     201     MG Road,bangalore
1000     301     MG Road,bangalore
1000     401     null

1000     501     null

2000     205     Plot # 5, Indira Nagar, Delhi

2000     305     Plot # 5, Indira Nagar, Delhi

2000     405     null

Please help me with the hql logic to achieve the above o/p

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.card_id
  FROM table-name E
 WHERE E.address IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Card_ID
  from table 
 group by Card_ID
having count(case when Address is null then 1 end) >0 --count null
       and 
       count(Address)>0 --count not null
;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for trying to help me out. When I try to execute your logic , it is yeilding me zero rows. I am running in hive. Please any suggestions

Comment: @Ramya check do you really have NULLs. not empty strings and change CASE accordingly. Try to exclude one of the HAVING sentences and check which of them caused filtering